# Advice on ElasticSearch query design

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I've got ES documents that looks like this:

```
{
   "auctionOn": "2018-01-01",
   "inspections: [
    {
       "startsOn": "2018-01-02 09:00",
       "endsOn": "2018-01-02 10:00"
    }
    ]
}
```

I need the following answers from a search (or multiple searches)

1. number of documents with an `auctionOn` in the future (e.g > now)
2. number of documents with an `inspection.startsOn` in the future (e.g > now)
3. date histogram (day breakdown) of the next 7 days, with # of documents with a `auctionOn` on that day
4. date histogram (day breakdown) of the next 7 days, with # of documents with a `inspection.startsOn` on that day

So, i'm trying to figure out how to efficiently get these answers. I know i can/should test out all different approaches, but i'm relatively new to ES so easier said than done.

Can someone give me a advice (or ideally, a query) on how to get these 4 values?

Ideas i had:

1. Query for all documents with an inspection/auction in the future. Create date histogram aggregations filtered to the next 7 days for both auction and inspections. Use range aggregations to get number of docs with auction/inspection > today.
   Pros: one search for all answers. Cons: lots of documents to aggregate over?
2. Create seperate searches (e.g msearch) for:

   - query all documents with an inspection in the next 7 days. aggregate by day.
   - query all documents with an auction in the next 7 days. aggregate by day.
   - query all documents with an inspection in the future. use hits to get total
   - query all documents with an auction in the future. use hits to get total.
     Pros: queries are simpler.. more cache hits? Cons: 4 seperate searches.

Can someone please guide me down the right path, and give me hints on how to do the query/aggregations?

Thanks

Comment: to person who voted to close due to 'too broad', care to explain how? i thought the problem was pretty specific..

Answer (score -1):

1. Use **range** query on the field **auctionOn** setting from as current date and **to** date as null.
2. Use **range** query inside nested query on the field **inspection.startsOn** as above.
3. Use **date histogram** aggregation using **interval** as **day**
4. Same as 3.) but inside **nested** aggregation
5. You can adjust all these in one query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. however, Not sure how this can be done in one query. Can you edit your answer with a sample query?

Comment: And also, 1 and 2 will filter results > 7 days ahead, so how can I get my last 2 figures? (# of auctions/inspections in future)